# JqueryUI highlight droppables on unaccepted objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a set of droppables, each associated with (accepting) one specific draggable. So draggable A can only be dropped on droppable A. What I want is for the droppables that *wont* accept the draggable to still get its hoverClass when I drag the draggable onto it.

The desired behavior is for the user not to know whether or not a draggable will be accepted until it is dropped, without losing the hoverClass entirely.

First of all: is there a configuration for this already, that I've missed?

If not: how would you go about solving the above? Would it be easier to manually add and remove hoverClass as needed, or to have the droppables accept all draggables, and manually revert on an invalid drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **activeClass**-option for the droppable. This allows you to highlight the droppables that accept the currently dragged draggables. But of course this is not what you want to do.

To get the desired behaviour, you really have to accept all draggables on all sortables.
There may be different solutions, one might be:

on **over** of the droppable determine, if the draggable is accepted(I mean accepted by you, not by the droppable, as there are all draggables accepted).
Assuming, you set **revert** to true in all draggables, you can now set the revert-option of the draggable to false(if its accepted). Otherwise add the class for highlightning if unaccepted  draggables are received.

On stop of the draggable remove the class set above and set revert back to true.

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rJkpu/

Comment: Hmm, what I want is the other way around: I *don't* want the user to know whether or not the draggable will be accepted before it is dropped.

Comment: added the other way to my post.

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly the behavior I want. +1 for now, and I'll accept if nothing more interesting shows up.